# Cannot install my apk on my old android device after using V1 and V2 Signature

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

I am trying to release my signed apk using android studio v3.2.1. But it is only working on my Redmi when i using V1 and V2. It shows the message like this "app not installed" on my Samsung device.

## Android Devices

1. Redmi Note 4X (Android 7.0NRD90M)
2. Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 (Android 5.0.2)

## V1 and V2

✓ Redmi Note 4X
✗ Samsung Galaxy Tab S2

## V1

✓ Redmi Note 4X
✓ Samsung Galaxy Tab S2

## V2

✓ Redmi Note 4X
✗ Samsung Galaxy Tab S2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after android studio 2.3, Two CheckBox added in Build apk generate.

From Android 7 to above (API 24), version 2 is introduced from Sign Signature. If you install APK with this method, your APK will be faster and if your APK file is edited by APKEditor and ... programs, install It will be with the problem.

But all of this will only be high for the API24, and if you just check the v2 checkbox, installing the APK below the API24 will be a problem and it's better to use v1 to sync your APK.

If you are using Android Studio with version 2.3 and want to deactivate Sign Signature v2, go to your Grid File Tool and add it to the signingConfigs skip and then the release scopes:

```
v2SigningEnabled false
```

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0#apk_signature_v2

Comment: Thank you, now i just install it using v1 signature.